# Sabre add and pay the airline ticket for angency account?

Tags: sabre

can any one provide the  detail step of add agency payment account method and sample payload for this kind of step? please share with me detail flow to add agency account payment.
I already had the Record locator but can not know how to pay.

Answer (score 0):

You must have the authorization and IATA accreditation to issue or apply payment. While you can register a form of payment (FOP), you cannot apply it (issue) without the necessary authorization. To become eligible to pay in SABRE, please contact IATA.